when I'm moving the any rig controller of my character, Blender crashes
I can't do animation in Blender. When I'm moving the any rig controller of my character , Blender crashes
This is only  happening when I try to move rig controller.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
